# Варианты git diff

Tags: git

Разбираюсь с вариантами `git diff`:

1) Чтобы сравнить `index` и `working area` - `git diff`

2) Чтобы сравнить `HEAD` и `working area` - `git diff HEAD`

3) Чтобы сравнить `index` и `HEAD` - `git diff --staged`

Это так?

Почему после коммита файла и последующего его изменения `git diff --staged` ничего не выдаёт - ведь индекс пустой, а `HEAD` нет - т.е. разница имеется?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin но почему после коммита файла и последующего его изменения `git diff` выдает дельту, хоть индекс и пустой?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а как же сравнить `index` и `WA`?

Comment: сейчас ответ напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще команда `diff` программы *git* показывает отличия между **двумя** деревьями файлов и каталогов. (чем, к слову, очень напоминает программу *diff*)

1. команда `diff` без параметров/опций показывает отличия рабочего каталога относительно дерева, содержащегося в *индексе*. если же *индекс* (пока) пуст, то показываются отличия от дерева, на которое указывает указатель `HEAD`.
2. если указать параметром *коммит* или *указатель* (*ветку* или *метку*):

   ```
   $ git diff коммит-или-указатель
   ```

   то сравниваться будет рабочий каталог и дерево, соответствующее данному коммиту или указателю.
3. если же указать опцию `--cached`, то сравниваться будет дерево, содержащееся в индексе, с деревом, на которое указывает указатель `HEAD`. и если индекс пуст, то, аналогично изложенному в  первом пункте, будет сравнение «`HEAD` с `HEAD`», т.е. никаких отличий не найдётся.
4. дополнительно к опции `--cached` можно упомянуть коммит или указатель:

   ```
   $ git diff --cached коммит-или-указатель
   ```

   тогда дерево, хранящееся в индексе, будет сравниваться не с `HEAD`, а с деревом, соответствующим данному коммиту или указателю. и, опять-таки, при отсутствии индекса, вместо него будет использоваться дерево, на которое указывает `HEAD`.

из всего изложенного следует, что команды

```
$ git diff --cached
$ git diff --cached HEAD
```

(в «нормальной» ситуации, когда `HEAD` указывает на существующий коммит или указатель) полностью эквивалентны.

> Почему после коммита файла и последующего его изменения git diff --staged ничего не выдаёт - ведь индекс пустой, а HEAD нет - т.е. разница имеется?

см. пункт 3: если индекс пуст, то будет сравнение «`HEAD` с `HEAD`», т.е. никаких отличий не найдётся.